# For loop running slow

Tags: c#, ajax, for-loop, outlook

I have a `Web Method` that is querying Outlook to grab all the distribution lists from the `Global Address List`.

This is grabbing over 4,000 distribution lists, which is exactly what I want it to do, but when it goes into the loop to pass the 4,000 lists into my `List` it takes over 3 minutes for it to finish the for loop. Can anyone see anything that is out of the ordinary and have an answer of why this may be happening?

Here is my code:

```
        public class DistributionListDetails
        {
            public int DistributionListId { get; set; }
            public string DistributionListEmail { get; set; }
        }

        List<DistributionListDetails> distributionLists = new List<DistributionListDetails>();
        int val = 0;

        //create Outlook application. 
        Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();

        //get Mapi NameSpace and Logon. 
        Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");

        //get Global Address List. 
        Outlook.AddressLists oDLs = oNS.AddressLists;
        Outlook.AddressList oGal = oDLs["Global Address List"];

        //get a specific distribution list. 
        string sDL = "TestDL";
        Outlook.AddressEntries oEntries = oGal.AddressEntries;
        Outlook.AddressEntry oDL = oEntries[sDL];

        if (oDL.Manager != null)
        distributionLists.Add(new DistributionListDetails
            {
                DistributionListId = val,
                DistributionListEmail = oDL.Manager.ToString()
            });

        //get all of the members of the distribution list. 
        oEntries = oDL.Members;
        Outlook.AddressEntry oEntry = default(Outlook.AddressEntry);

        int i = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= oGal.AddressEntries.Count && i <= 10; i++)
        {
            oEntry = oGal.AddressEntries[i];
            distributionLists.Add(new DistributionListDetails
            {
                DistributionListId = val,
                DistributionListEmail = oEntry.Name
            });
        }
```

**NOTE**: I am binding the returned list from the loop to a dropdown via AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the query to AD isn't the bottleneck, try this LINQ on for size.  It replaces your last loop.

```
distributionLists.AddRange(oGal.AddressEntries
  .Cast<Outlook.AddressEntry>()
  .Select(
    x => new DistributionListDetails 
    { 
        DistributionListId = val, 
        DiestributionListEmail = x.Name
    }));
```

Edit: Force cast the AddressEntries into an IQueryable so select will work.

Comment: It would make no difference - LINQ does not do magic. It replaces an explicit loop with something that looks cool but does the same. Outlook would not know the difference.

Comment: Yeah, that gives me the error "Microsoft.Office.Interop.AddressEntries does not contain a definition for Select". I wonder if there is an alternative for Select?

Comment: Maybe there isn't a solution to make this run faster?

Comment: No, it's eliminating 4000 calls to the List's Add method which prevents constant growth of the list whereas AddRange grows the list to the necessary size, then adds the objects.

Comment: @TheSharpNinja to be honest I have never touched LINQ, how would I limit to to only giving me 10 objects for my list? Kind of like I am in my loop (just so I can compare the speeds of both, for testing purposes)

Comment: Add .Take(10) to the end of the method chain.

Comment: @TheSharpNinja this seems to work pretty nice in my case. It cut it from taking 17 seconds to pull 10 using the for loop to only taking 2 seconds using LINQ. Thank you very much

Comment: I suspect that iterating the list is pretty expensive because of all of the COM interop going on.  Try adding a .ToList() between the cast and select and see if that further speeds things up.  You may also consider breaking up the task into chunks and running it in threads so that the COM interop load is spread across the processor cores.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are running this method to grab distribution lists every time someone calls this method. Instead of doing that, it's better to cachce the distribution lists and access them from cache when needed.

1. Create a repository class for the distribution lists
2. When a user calls this method for the first time, load the
       repository from outlook using your method. Then Store it in
       [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx).
       You have to select a suitable policy for caching. For an example if,
       you need to refresh your cached distribution list hourly basis, you
       have to use absolute expiration and set it to 1hr. If not, you can
       use sliding expiration which extends the life time of the cached
       object as users access the lists.
3. Your repository should first check if the cached object is
   available, if yes, use it. Else load it again using the above
   method.

Comment: It depends on how dynamic the distribution lists are. If they change very frequently, it's better to use absolute expiration.